# ASP.NET Web API action method support in JQuery with intellisense

Tags: c#, json, jquery, asp.net-web-api

ASP.NET Web API action methods return JSON result and are called through JQuery in my project. I found that for this I ended up writing almost similar code for all action methods. Moreover I felt my approach gets bit more complicated when I pass classes (normal or nested). I have to call JSON.stringfy to normalize it.

Keeping this mind I started out with writting T4 template which will generate these calling mechanisms for me with all parameters. Though its early in process I am looking for good suggestions to achieve this. Following are the steps I am planning to follow in same.

- Get Core Assembly where ApiController resides
- Identify ApiController classes
- Identify action methods in given ApiController class
- Identify extra properties of action method like custom route, get or post
- Identify parameters of method
- Identify if any parameter is complex (class)
- Identify members of complex type (recursive if member is also complex)
- identify if any parameter is Array - perform above 3 steps for its base type
- [optional] Identify return type and perform above 4 steps,

  - *optional cause I do not have direct use of it.*
- Generate JavaScript based on above information.
- Generate Documentation for above methods based on available documentation for methods and parameters.

  - *Am totally black about this option. I feel this option is pretty important as there is good chance of typos in complex handling.*

I have already did my searching and could not find any T4 template which does this. Frankly am bit surprised on this part, as I find it so obivious for working on complex applications with Web Api.

**Questions**

- Does this idea sounds feasible?
- Is there any project which already does this?

Comment: I might be missing something, but what is your question? :)

Comment: Just added questions :)